# ESPN NBA web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, espn

I had been using a python program to get scores of NFL, NBA and Soccer games from the ESPN site. The program was working good until one day it stopped working. The program would give me the output in the format.

Date | Home Team Name | Home Team Score | Away Team Name | Away Team score

The error I am getting is: [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LkG7.png)

Could someone help me explain the error and help me get this program running again or suggest any alternative way to get it running?

The below code is for ESPN NBA and the url would be
https://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20221228

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

OutPut = "/Users/Spring 2023/NBA ESPN/OutPut/"
FileName = "ESPN_NBA.csv"
input_date = "12/28/2022" #MM/DD/YYYY
input_end_date = "12/30/2022" #MM/DD/YYYY

year = input_date[-4:]
month = input_date[:2]
day = input_date[3:5]

year1 = int(input_date[-4:])
month1 = int(input_date[:2])
day1 = int(input_date[3:5])

end_year = input_end_date[-4:]
end_month = input_end_date[:2]
end_day = input_end_date[3:5]

end_year1 = int(input_end_date[-4:])
end_month1 = int(input_end_date[:2])
end_day1 = int(input_end_date[3:5])

Date = date(year1,month1,day1)
Date

end_date = date(end_year1,end_month1,end_day1)
end_date

timedelta = end_date - Date

n = timedelta.days+1

url_list = []


a=0

year1 = int(input_date[-4:])
month1 = int(input_date[:2])
day1 = int(input_date[3:5])


while a<n:

    if a == 0:
        day1 = day1
        month1 = month1
        year1 = year1

    elif month1 in [1,3,5,7,8,10]:
        if day1 == 31:
            day1 = 1
            month1 = month1+1
        else:
            day1 = day1+1


    elif month1 == 2:
        if day1 == 28:
            day1 = 1
            month1 = month1+1

        else:
            day1 = day1+1

    elif month1 in [4,6,9,11]:
        if day1 == 30:
            day1 = 1
            month1 = month1+1

        else:
            day1 = day1+1

    elif month1 == 12:
        if day1 == 31:
            day1 = 1
            month1 = 1
            year1 = year1+1

        else:
            day1 = day1+1

    if month1 in range(1,10):
        month = '0' + str(month1)
    else:
        month = str(month1)
    if day1 in range(1,10):
        day = '0' + str(day1)
    else:
        day = str(day1)

    year = str(year1)
    
    url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/"+str(year)+str(month)+str(day)
    url_list.append(url)

    a = a+1


url_list


away_team = []
home_team = []
away_team_score = []
home_team_score = []
gamedate = []

for url in url_list:
    try:
        response = urlopen(url)
    except Exception:    
        print("No games played on "+url)
        continue
        
    urlname = requests.get(url)
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urlname.text,'lxml')

    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            name = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'ScoreCell__TeamName ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName truncate db'})[i]
        except Exception:
            break

        name = name.get_text()
        try:
            score = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'ScoreCell__Score h4 clr-gray-01 fw-heavy tar ScoreCell_Score--scoreboard pl2'})[i]
        except Exception:
            break


        score = score.get_text()

        if i%2 == 0:
            away_team.append(name)
            away_team_score.append(score)

        else:
            home_team.append(name)
            home_team_score.append(score)
            gamedate.append(url[-4:-2]+"/"+url[-2:]+"/"+url[-8:-4])

        i = i + 1
    
web_scraping = list (zip(gamedate, home_team, home_team_score, away_team, away_team_score))
web_scraping_df = pd.DataFrame(web_scraping, columns = ['Date','home_team','home_team_score','away_team','away_team_score'])
web_scraping_df.to_csv(OutPut+FileName, index = False)

count_df = []
count_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([web_scraping_df['home_team'],web_scraping_df['away_team']]).value_counts(), columns = ['Count'])
count_df.index.rename('Team Name', inplace=True)    
count_df_file = "count_"+FileName
    
count_df.to_csv(OutPut+count_df_file,index = True, header=True)



print("File Saved")
```

I tried running each line and figured that the program was breaking at `urlname = requests.get(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20221228"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for s in soup.select(".Scoreboard"):
    name1, name2 = [n.get_text(strip=True) for n in s.select(".ScoreCell__TeamName")]
    score1, score2 = [n.get_text(strip=True) for n in s.select(".ScoreCell__Score")]
    date = s.find_previous("h3", class_="Card__Header__Title").text
    print(f"{date:<30} {name1:^20} {score1:^5} - {score2:^5} {name2:^20}")
```

Prints:

```
Wednesday, December 28, 2022          Magic          101  -  121        Pistons       
Wednesday, December 28, 2022           Suns          102  -  127        Wizards       
Wednesday, December 28, 2022           Nets          108  -  107         Hawks        
Wednesday, December 28, 2022          Lakers         98   -  112          Heat        
Wednesday, December 28, 2022          Bucks          113  -  119         Bulls        
Wednesday, December 28, 2022       Timberwolves      118  -  119        Pelicans      
Wednesday, December 28, 2022           Jazz          107  -  112        Warriors      
Wednesday, December 28, 2022         Nuggets         126  -  127         Kings
```